# Filtering out null collection property using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to extract a subset of a list based on a property. That property is itself a collection and I'm only interested in the values where this collection is not null

My code is:

```
var subGroupCollection = groupContext.SubGroups.Where(sg => sg.Holds != null).ToList();
```

I get the following run-time error:

*Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[WW2.Hold, WW2, Version=6.0.5848.30559, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.*

"Holds" is the name of the collection property(this is a HashSet of Hold objects)

What's the issue here and is there an obvious solution?

Comment: Have you tried `sg.Holds.Count() > 0` or `sg.Holds.Any()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The collection will never be `null` in EF.  It might be *empty*, but it will never be `null`.  In fact, you can't even compare the entire collection to `null`, which is exactly what the error is telling you.  If you want to get items where that collection has any items, use `Any` to determine that.